# Why did permalinks setting affect the pages?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, templates

I created custom post type and a page template named template-tv.php. The custom post type I created (in https://generatewp.com/post-type/) is similar to "**Post**" in admin menu. I created a page called TV and assigned this template to the page. However, I found out that the template will only display if I change the permalinks settings. If I use post name as in http://www.example.com/sample-post/, it doesn't display the page template. It only display the archive.php. But when I change it to Numeric, as in http://www.example.comarchives/123, it was able to display the page template. I even tried to change the **'has_archive'** in the array list to false, but it didn't work... Help? It never happened to me before..

The theme I was using is child theme of Monday theme (https://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-themes/the-monday/)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's a conflict with your post type key and page slug. Try changing your page's slug to something different and see if it changes anything.